# jQuery DatePicker - set default date on open

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I have two date boxes: From and To.

- If the user clicks in To and From is empty, it should default to the current date.
- If the user clicks in To and From has a value, it should default to From's value.
- If the user clicks in To and To already has a value, it should default to THAT value.

Essentially, if I click in From, set it to July, then click in To, I don't want to have to navigate all the way to July again.

I know I can set defaultDate, but how can I set this dynamically when the datepicker opens?  I want to be able to register a function that calls before datepicker opens, so I can evaluate the state and set the correct defaultDate.

Comment: use events from one to update options for the other. API shows you how to update options as well as all the various events available

Comment: That's what I'm looking for, a suitable event.  The API docs don't seem to list any events: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Comment: ok...is bad documentation but they are listed as `options` like `onSelect`

Comment: Yeah, they have onClose, onSelect and onChangeMonthYear - I need an onOpen or onShow.

Comment: why can't use use `onSelect`? Or you can use a `focus()` handler of your own

Comment: Yeah, I can use onSelect - I guess I just needed to think about it the other way around - changing the default date when the first one is set, not when the second one is open.  I'll post an answer with some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to charlietfl in the comments for making me realise I just needed to think about it the other way round:

```
$("input.datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (dateText) {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == 'FromDate') {
            $('input#ToDate').datepicker("option", "defaultDate", dateText);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JavaScript to set the default date to your end date to be the same day in as your start date. You can dynamically set this by using the onchange function.

```
 <input type="text" id="start" value="0" name="start" onchange="changeText();">
<input type="text" id="end" value="0" name="end" > 


<script type="text/javascript">
function changeText(){
        var x = document.getElementById("start").value;
        document.getElementById('end').value = x;
}
</script>
```

Comment: That code has nothing to do with jQuery DatePicker

Comment: Yes it does.. it writes the value in the text field which is what date picker uses.. try it out.